# Azure ubuntu | Acquiring an agent from the cloud:Request queue position information is unavailable

Tags: azure-pipelines

I am unable to run the jobs in azure pipelines when I try to run the job I am facing the below issue. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: ubuntu-latest
Queued: Today at 20:39 [manage parallel jobs]

Acquiring an agent from the cloud:
Request queue position information is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Pipelines in your region may be impacted by a live site incident, resulting in possible pipeline delays. There is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which could affected these services. Check the [status](https://status.dev.azure.com/) here.

[image]

You can go to Project settings->Agent pools->click "Azure Pipelines" pool->click "Agents" tab to check agent status.

If the issue still exists, you can cancel the running job and try to specify other vm image to see if the same issue exists.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
```

If the above way does not work, you can try to create a new pipeline.